# "love most" versus "love the most"

Tags: articles, definite-article, superlatives

I'd like to know if there is something I should know about when making a decision to use/not to use the article with *most* when it modifies the verb. For example,

> My main passion are the horses that's what I *love **the most*** about
>   the sport.
>
> Each of us has to find what we *love **most*** about our profession.
>
> It's having your family and your friends alive, and that's what
>   *matters **the most***.
>
> Put yourself in your partner's shoes to gain perspective on what
>   *matters **most***.

Is this again one of those cases of personal preference, or is there a better explanation?

I read on another forum that when *love most* is followed by *about*, *the* is often ommitted and, from my research, it really seems to be the case. So does it depend on what words go next?

I thought it was the case with formality/informality as the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/most) states, but it doesn't sound very convincing to me. Also, both the Corpus of Contemporary American English and google books give more results for "love most/matter most" versus "love the most/matter the most".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Most* has [two closely-related meanings](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/the+most#most_1).

> 1 the *largest* in number or amount
>    2 *more than half / almost all* of somebody/something

As that OALD link says, ***the*** most is often used for the first meaning - but informally, *the* is often omitted. It's *never* used with the second meaning.

---

Suppose [The Queen of Hearts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Queen_of_Hearts_%28poem%29) were to ask *"Who ate my tarts?"*...

> A1: "The knave ate **the** most"
>    A2: "The knave ate most"

If several courtiers ate *one* tart each, but the knave ate *two*, then either answer could validly be given, since he ate *more than anyone else* (but note that A1 is a "very slightly formal" usage).

But if the knave actually ate *more than half* (but not *all*) of the tarts, only A2 is correct. Though the Queen might not understand that intended distinction, since *the* could be omitted anyway.

---

It's worth making the point that *the* is never included when *most* simply means *very*...

> "I am **most** grateful for your help"

...but interestingly, whereas in...

> "There were 50 people there, **at** [the] **most**"

... *the* is normally omitted, it's *almost always* included if we add *very* as an intensifier...

> "There were 50 people there, **at the very most**"

Comment: Thanks for stressing the difference in meaning in "ate (the) most"! But with abstract verbs like "love" or "matter", it's difficult to apply the same logic. And since "most" without the article is correct either way, I think I'm going to stick to that.

Comment: @stillenat: I'm not sure you *can* apply "most" to abstract verbs with sense #2 above. I can only think of constructions like *"We **mostly** love weddings"* (which I suppose could mean either more than half of us love weddings, or we love more than half of all weddings). But I think you've made a wise decision - omit "the" every time and you shouldn't go far wrong. Some might not be keen on [at very most](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+very+most%2Cat+the+very+most&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) in my final point, but it *does* validly occur.

Comment: This answer is well explained. "I am *the* most grateful" would in fact have a completely different meaning: "I am the person who is most grateful out of all the people who are grateful."

Comment: In the first part you say: "_informally, 'the' is often omitted_", and in the second part you contradict that with "_note that A1 is a 'very slightly informal' usage_". I guess that's just a typo. But I really don't understand why "_if the knave actually ate more than half (but not all) of the tarts, only A2 is correct_". Wouldn't it still be true that the knave ate the largest in number or amount? So wouldn't A1 and A2 be both true, in two different senses?

Comment: @Færd: I think you're right about the typo. I don't recall my exact thought processes at the time, but looking at it now I'd say if the knave ate more than anyone else (but not more than half in total), then including the article in A1 in order to convey that would be a very slightly *formal* usage. As to your second point - again, strictly speaking you're right. I think I must have had an implicit *if the speaker doesn't intend to mislead* in mind.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Taking into account what you wrote in your answer. Could one say "He gave money most" meaning "Most of what he gave was money"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Could you tell me if this reasoning is correct? – 

- Johnson owns the most companies in this neighborhood. (Compared to Carl and Catalina, for example)

- Johnson owns most companies in this neighborhood. (Than everybody else)

Comment: @Portugueseporto: Yes - I think you've got it! If Johnson owns 4 local companies, and Carl and Catalina own 3 each, *Johnson owns **the** most companies locally*, even though he only owns 40% of the total. If you *don't* include the highlighted article, that strongly implies Johnson owns ***at least 50%*** of all the companies.

Comment: @Thunder05: No - you *can't* say *He gave money most*. The word "most" must come *before* the noun it modifies *(**money**)*. You can either include the article *(He gave **the** most money)* or not, as per reply to Portugueseporto above.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, friend! I hope you have a nice week. Take care.

Answer (score 3):

In your example sentences either is correct, though simply using *most* without *the* is more idiomatic. Using *the most* rather than just *most* is only required in sentences like this one:

> The most important thing you need to take with you on a camping trip is water.

That's because *the most important thing* is the subject; the *the* actually is paired with *thing*, I think, because it remains if we change the sentence to:

> The thing you need to take with you on a camping trip is water.

But this is the only case I'm aware of where *the most* is required, not optional.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that "most" without "the" is more idiomatic, because that's exactly what I'm currently working on. I'm trying to make my speech sound as idiomatic and natural as I possibly can.