# Is there always a "the" before a superlative adjective?

Tags: articles, word-order, inversion, superlatives

For example:

> I could not face being alone again and losing the person **dearest** to me.

I wonder why there is no "the" in front of "dearest".

Comment: When Melania Trump attempted to sloganeer her way into the American people's hearts with the motto "Be Best", criticism was rapid -- that may be Slovenian, but it's not English. Be warned -- or rather, be the warnedest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The *noun* *superlative*

The **the** is there, *two* words ahead of the superlative adjective. Usually in English the adjective comes ahead of the noun, but in this sentence it comes after the noun. **The** is not so flexible,* so it still precedes the noun. You could also write it like this:

> (1) I could not face being alone again and losing **the dearest person** to me.

**The *noun* *superlative*** is actually a very standard construction. Here are some typical examples:

> **The person most capable** should be chosen for the job.
>
> **The person last to use** the bathroom is responsible for cleaning it up.
>
> The motion-picture camera is **the tool closest** to the human sense of observation. [[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZeNKR2Mu59QC&lpg=PA248&dq=%22the%20tool%20closest%22&pg=PA248#v=onepage&q=%22the%20tool%20closest%22&f=false)]

As your example and the last two examples illustrate, the reason for putting the superlative after the noun is often to avoid separating the superlative from a prepositional phrase that modifies it: “dearest to me”, “closest to [something]”. My sentence (1) sounds a little awkward because it separates the superlative from its prepositional phrase, though it’s still grammatical and comprehensible. If you really wanted to put **dearest** first, you’d probably rewrite it with a phrase or clause that modifies the noun phrase as a whole, although this invokes a different sense of **dearest** (no longer the superlative of *dear to me* but *dear* to general):

> (2) I could not face being alone again and losing **the dearest person** I know.

When **the** modifies the adjective but the noun won’t take an article, then you have to put **the** after the noun:

> Ladies and gentlemen, meet **Henry the Eighth**, also known as **Henry the Fattest**,  **Henry the Meanest**, and **Henry the Worst** (well, the worst after King John).

### You actually don’t need *the*

There actually isn’t any special rule that a superlative requires **the**. It’s just that **a** doesn’t make sense there, since **a** means to pick one of many, and by definition a superlative has only one instance. But you can use other [determiners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner) that can refer to a unique instance, including no article at all:

> …**that most cunning** of animals, the fox. [[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=79m3tn1Ueu8C&lpg=PA306&dq=%22that%20most%20cunning%22&pg=PA306#v=onepage&q=%22that%20most%20cunning%22&f=false)]
>
> I sent **my fastest galloper** to Daleer Khan. [[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=43Eh65HVjDEC&lpg=PA325&dq=%22my%20fastest%22&pg=PA325#v=onepage&q=%22my%20fastest%22&f=false)]
>
> **This fastest car** will not be in garages any time soon. [[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=SVUBAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP3&dq=%22this%20fastest%22&pg=PP3#v=onepage&q=%22this%20fastest%22&f=false). This one is unusual, but it shows that it can be done. Context must provide something for **this** to point to.]
>
> Alan seemed **most likely** to succeed. [[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=2hZdZcjQhZoC&lpg=PA9&dq=%22seemed%20most%20likely%20to%20succeed%22&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q=%22seemed%20most%20likely%20to%20succeed%22&f=false)]
>
> “Rapunzel is **fairest** of all.” [[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=lacyAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA98&dq=%22fairest%20of%20all%22&pg=PA98#v=onepage&q=%22fairest%20of%20all%22&f=false)]

You can even put **a** in front of a superlative when you intend the superlative to designate only a very high degree of something rather than the one item with the highest degree:

> The hermitage is **a most curious** piece of architecture. [[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=f3A-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA130&dq=%22a+most+curious%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=I5C4VIKHF9T-yQTezILwDA&ved=0CCcQuwUwAjgU#v=onepage&q=%22a%20most%20curious%22&f=false)]

---

<sup>* But maybe CarSmack can figure out a phrase of the form ***adj* *noun* the** (not like “Henry the Eighth”, etc.).</sup>

Comment: Re: *You actually don’t need the*: besides *the*, the other definite determiners are *this/that/these/those* and possessive pronouns. So 'that most cunning...' and 'this fatest car' work. *However,* both *most likely to suceed* and *fairest of all* work like titles or a unique role, which do not need the article: "You can be champion of the world, Rocky." "She was appointed head coach of the volleyball team." [See also](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56365/omission-of-the-in-elected-him-president-and-made-captain). *Edit:* otherwise, superlatives usually do take *the.*

Comment: @CarSmack Thanks. I'll add an example with a possessive pronoun.

Comment: In your final example, "a most curious", most used in this way is equivalent to "very". The correct term for this is an **intensifier** rather than a superlative.  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/most

Comment: @JavaLatte Indeed there are many terminologies for English grammar, varying from the traditional terminology to highly technical terminologies only of interest to linguists. Even on that freedictionary page, some dictionaries say "intensifier" and some don't. The traditional terminology has many flaws, but it has the advantage of being common knowledge among English speakers, so I'm (mostly) using it here. I think adding another grammar term would only confuse my point about not needing "the". The concept is there, just not the word "intensifier". Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: apparently "noun superlative" is not a grammatical term.

Comment: @PHPst _noun superlative_ is in italics to indicate that it means "a noun" followed by "a superlative" (adjective).

Answer (score 4):

What? Are you going to say: *the person the dearest*? :)

*Dearest* is an adjective that that has been placed after the noun.

Since *the* modifies the whole noun phrase, *the* is placed at the beginning of the noun phrase, *ie* before *person*.

You would also not put an article before *dearest* when you use it at the beginning of a letter or before a comparative/superlative adverb preceding *dearest:*

*Dearest* John,
We had the most dreariest weather today. Unfortunately, I lost the person (most) dear to me when he stepped on a landmine.
Yours sincerely,
Roxanne

Note: *most dearest* is considered nonstandard, because both *most* and *-est* mark the quality *superlative*. But people also use *best* to describe the *better* of two people, when it makes more sense to use *better* since *better* is a comparative.

Answer (score 1):

*dearest* modifies the noun *person*, so *person* gets the article *the*.

Answer (score 1):

https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/47049/628 provides a clearer answer. Applying it to your example, "dearest" is a predicative adjective so the article is optional. To reveal that it is a predicative adjective you can re-write it as:

> I could not face being alone again and losing the person who is dearest to me.