# He is making the problem worst/worse

Tags: superlatives

Is this correct?

> He is making the problem worst.

I have a feeling that it is wrong and **worst** should be **worse** but I couldn't explain why it is wrong.

So to confirm, is **worst** in the example sentence correct and sounds natural? If it is wrong, what is the reason?

Answer (score 3):

A comparative like **worse** needs something to compare *with*, which can be implied:

> He is making the problem worse (than before).

The usage of **worst** could be used in the example below. Notice the definite article "the" must be used with **worst**:

> This is the worst problem he has ever faced.

Comment: But why *worst* in *making the problem worst* wrong?

Comment: Perhaps "He is making the problem the worst ever".

Comment: Please see this [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46923/is-there-always-a-the-before-a-superlative-adjective).

Comment: comparative: worse. This is worse than that. superlative: This is the worst [whatever].