# Use of indefinite article

Tags: grammar

Here are two complete sentences

> This is the weirdest case of scientific field.
>
> This is the weirdest case of a scientific field.

I just want to know which is grammatically correct, with an "a" or without one?

I am talking about a particular scientific field within science (there are many). The question can be simplified as follows: a given particular scientific field, say biology, is it

> a case of scientific field

or

> a case of a scientific field

Thanks!

Comment: @user354948 - In general, if you want to help us understand your question better, you should edit your question and add **more** details, not remove details. Just a hint; see our [_Details, Please_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post for more helpful information.

Comment: @J.R. In my experience, simplifying goes a longer way towards understanding than making it more complex and convoluted by adding...

Comment: When it comes to a language question, additional details won't usually make a question more complex or more convoluted. Instead, the addition information typically makes the question more focused and more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure that the first sentence is grammatically correct so let's try breaking down the second sentence:

> This...

**This** indicates that a context has been established (or will be established) - i.e out of 3 weird cases, the second case is the weirdest and by establishing context you are making it very specific (non-generic) - not any other case but *this* particular case: the 2nd case out of the 3 weird cases.

> This is the weirdest...

When using [superlatives](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/superlative), you *normally* use an indefinite article (**the**) because using a definite article (**a**) wouldn't make sense, i.e you wouldn't say "This is a weirdest...". You can take a look at [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/46927) for more clarification.

> This is the weirdest case of a scientific field.

Now we start to deal with countable vs uncountable nouns. *Scientific field* is a countable noun (i.e you can count how many fields there are: Physics, Chemistry, Biology, etc) - I'm grouping the word "scientific" with the word "field" but the important part here is "field" because we have many scientific fields and using **a** means you are picking a particular field (out of the many fields we have).

Summary - go with the 2nd sentence, because it would mean:

> Out of the many scientific fields we have, we'll be focusing on **a**
>   particular field: Physics. And, out of the 3 weird cases we have
>   established (or will establish), case #2 is **the** weirdest.

But with most things in English, you will find exceptions.

Comment: So, the "a" has to be there, I thought so, thanks. That was my only doubt. I wonder why the user David answered me that "neither sentence is English". I hope he would explain why he thinks that the 2nd sentence is not English. Anyway, for now your answer is accepted!