# Using 'most': with or without 'the'?

Tags: articles, definite-article, superlatives

I thought we need "the" before the word most. 
Such as in:

> She is **the** most beautiful girl.

But, I came across this sentence:

> **Most incredible** is how many Islamic scholars have popped up over the past few years.

Why isn't there "**the**" before the word "**most**" ? I know "**the**" is not needed if the word afterward is an adverb as in:

*I like it most.*

However, "incredible" isn't being used as an adverb here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to @GoDucks' nice answer, when *most* means *very*, *exceedingly* or *extremely* as an **intensifier**, you should not use the definite article *the*. It could be a better explanation because there is a case where *the* is not used even though there is a noun after "most + adjective", i.e.:

> This is most dangerous procedure.

The above sentence doesn't mean that the procedure is the most dangerous procedure of all the procedures. It just indicates a degree of danger that the procedure carries.

Therefore, whenever you see the word *most* without articles, you could try to replace it with the intensifiers I suggested above, i.e.:

> Most (very, exceedingly, extremely) incredible is how many Islamic
>   scholars have popped up over the past few years.
>
> This is most (very, exceedingly, extremely) dangerous procedure.

Comment: Since "procedure" is a singular count noun, shouldn't it be "This is **a** most dangerous procedure."?

Comment: @CopperKettle Procedure has a mass noun usage, too.

Comment: @CopperKettle Let's use an easier to recognize mass noun: *This is most dangerous justice.* I would tend to place the *most + adjective* **after** the noun: *This is justice most dangerous* or *This is news most strange*. Either way  it's not something you see every day. It is most unusual grammar, or grammar most unusual.

Comment: Or indeed, [Murder Most Foul](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0058383/), which works so much better  than *Most Foul Murder*! But +1 to Ranthony for mentioning mass nouns with *most + adjective*.

Answer (score 8):

Before a singular count noun modified by *'most' plus an adjective* you need a determiner, and this can include either the definite article or indefinite article. So technically, one could say both

> She is the most beautiful girl.

and

> She is a most beautiful girl.

For the difference in usage, see [a most talented writer -- grammar -- why not "the most talented writer"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39826/a-most-talented-writer-grammar-why-not-the-most-talented-writer).

For an adjective only, without any following noun, you use *most* by itself, **because there is no noun**.

> *Most beautiful* was the girl I knew in high school.
>
> The girl next door was *most beautiful*.
>
> *Most incredible* is how many...

We have to be careful because in some situations, the noun can be ellided or implied. It should be clear from context if this is the case:

> The girl next door was the most beautiful (girl).
>
> The most astonishing (fact) is that zombies are real.

Curiously, to use an implied or ellided noun with the *indefinite article* seems doubtful as to its grammaticality.

> ?The girl next door was a most beautiful.

The question mark (?) marks this sentence as having questionable grammaticality. That is  not all people will judge it to be grammatical. Thinking about it, I can think of contexts where it would be grammatical, but it would be rare.

Comment: +1 and a very good answer. I liked the part *(most by itself...)*, which is an answer to another *askable* question!