# "it is the lattice enthalpy which has fallen most" - shouldn't it be "has fallen the most"?

Tags: articles

From [Chemguide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group7/halideions.html#top):

> Chlorine to iodine
>
> Considering the halogens from chlorine to iodine, it is the lattice enthalpy which **has fallen most**. It falls by 87 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>. By contrast, the heat needed to remove the electron has only fallen by 54 kJ mol<sup>-1</sup>.

Shouldn't it be "has fallen **the** most"?

There are several characteristics, and one has fallen by the highest amount compared with the others.

Comment: Either is fine. ............   New housing starts are up in Q2, but of all the economic strength indicators, the new jobs number has risen (the) most.

Comment: As an adverbal use of **most**, it's fine without a definite article, for example in the sentence "That was one of things she liked most about him".

Comment: P.S. "Practical English Usage, Unit 356.5" (Damkerng)

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[most versus the most](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7038/most-versus-the-most)*. Also of interest is *[Are “most” and “the most” the same?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18571)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following:

> it is **the** lattice enthalpy which has fallen most

or

> it is lattice enthalpy which has fallen **the** most

A repetitive use of "the" makes it somewhat unnatural, although not grammatically incorrect.